# Unable to display products of home page in Magento 1.8.1

Tags: magento

After successful installation of `Magento 1.8.1` in a system. Everything works fine, but unable to display products on the home page. As posted on Magento website, I modified the home page design using admin interface `CMS >> Pages >> Home Page >> Design`.
As shown in the  [Magento Wiki page](https://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/groups/248/display_products_on_home_page) below lines were added in the second line of home page design -

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

Still, the products are not displayed on home page.
What should be done to display the products on home page.
I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 server, with MySQL 5.5 database and Magento version 1.8.1 downloaded using SVN

Comment: Does the products are in stock and have proper inventory ?

Comment: Yes products are in stock, but to confirm pls check me where can I check this.

Comment: I can also view this products from search, but not on home page

Comment: Is the template file catalog/product/new.phtml really called on your home page ?

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy How can I find that?

Comment: Turn on the template path hints from your admin

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy How can I do that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49012/discussion-between-slimshadddyyy-and-user3004356)

Comment: What does it say in `var/log/system.log` and `var/log/exception.log`?   Is it a valid template file?  Does that block exist?

Comment: @user3004356 so what's the solution i have the same probleme

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy so what's the solution i have the same probleme

Comment: There are no products matching the selection. thats what it gives for me :(

Comment: For that i need to check your catalog from backend

Answer (score 4):

In your xml file add this and remove the block from CMS > Home Page section

```
<cms_index_index>
  <reference name="content">

  <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new"  as="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"/>

  </reference>
</cms_index_index>
```

Comment: what will be the different between write in xml file and cms home page content area?

Comment: XML file will have all the information regarding your layout and blocks being called. A single file telling you the layout of your customization's done. You can obviously place in CMS pages but then when you move to Staging or Live Environment you again need to add those blocks in CMS pages. Also if any encounter any issue in layout you can check your XML file only without going in backend and check CMS pages too.

Comment: Thanks for your sharing info @Slimshadddy +1 for you

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy can you tell me that i should copy this code where? what do you mean about xml file? where is it?

Answer (score 2):

Please check this:

> *New product doesn’t mean that you’ve recently added them; only products explicitly marked as new using ‘Set Product as New from Date’ and ‘Set Product as New to Date’ options in the ‘General’ product information page in the admin tool will be shown.*

First you have to check if product is define *new product* in manage product or not. If not then you have to assign product as *new product* then and then it display in new product. Please check image

[image]

Then you have to check product is in stock. and don't forgot to clear cache after changes

Let me know it helps you any way

Comment: I have the set the date and also I checked its status. Everything is fine.

Comment: I can search this products in search box and view the products but cannot view it directly on home page

Comment: your product new date start from today ?

Comment: New date from - 3/3/2014 and New Date to - 3/21/2014

Comment: With the dates you set you would need to wait until 3/14/2014 to have your products displayed in home page.

Comment: please try to new date 3/5/2014 to 3/21/2014

Comment: is your cache disable?

Comment: @KeyurShah I tried the new date, but nothing happened. Cache management page says all cache enabled

Comment: please try to disable cache or refresh cache it works for you

Comment: you are using any custom theme ?

Answer (score 2):

I was have the same problem sometimes. Need to check products quantity, status set to enabled, products must be in stock. Also need to re-index data and clear all caches. After all products will be display in the site homepage.

Comment: I have checked everything, everything is fine.

Comment: Is there any XML I can change either, or should it be only through CMS

Answer (score 2):

1. Step 1: Login into your Magento Admin Dashboard;

   2. Step 2: Go to: CMS -> Pages -> And choose Home Page;
   3. Step 3: Now you must see the some edit options which will be applied for the HomePage.
   4. Step 4: Go to: Contet Tab from left;
   5. Step 5: Add following snippet in the WYSIWYG (As know as “What You See Is What You Get”)

;

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```