# Unable to display products of home page in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento

I add some products in magento panel but when i go to home page these are not to be show!!!!

I also test [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037967/magento-show-new-products-on-home-page) but it is not work.

I also see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22189210/unable-to-display-products-of-home-page-in-magento-1-8-1) but i don't know which xml file it does mean!

Please if any one know that how can i fix this problem help me.

Thank you

Comment: I find my answer, because i add 10 product and then clear cache these products does not to be show in home, i delete products and add one by one and after adding one product clear cache and every thing is ok, all products show in home page.

Answer (score 0):

Login into magento admin Now click on any product which you have created
Now  Set Product as New from Date and Set Product as New to Date

Now go to CMS home page now click on content then click on show/hide editor then click on insert widget now select Catalog new Product list then save.

Now clean magento cache and check in frontend

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show products of specific category in Home page, try this:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" category_id="3" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

If you want to show new products in Home Page:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

But in this case you need to set values of **Set Product as New from Date** and **Set Product as New to Date** for products which you want to show in this list.

**Note:** If the problem still persists, then check:

- products quantity > 0
- stock availability must be in stock
- status must be enabled
- product must be either in catalog or search or catalog/search

Comment: when i add new product i set date for it but set products new to date, how can i set it?

Comment: This is to help you to hide products from new products list after specific date.

you can set it to a specific date by clicking on calendar icon and choosing date from calendar.

Comment: i set date for every product but these are not show in home page, when i add these products i clear cache when i add 10 product and i don't clear cache after adding every product, is it possible because i clear cache after adding 10 product these are not to be show? now i add another product and just this product show in home page but until 10 product does not show!!!

Comment: You can do one thing: Refresh cache, Disable cache and then add all products then refresh cache and at last enable cache.